# Share a collection of datas with two entities

Tags: hibernate, share, hibernate-annotations

I can't find any answer on Internet about my question, so I hope to have some information here :-)

Just for information, here is my first class, Attribut :

```
@Entity
@Table(name="T_ATTRIBUT")
public class Attribut implements Serializable{

private long id;

private Set<LocString> label = new HashSet<LocString>(0);

  @ManyToMany(fetch=FetchType.EAGER, cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
public Set<LocString> getLabel() {
    return label;
}
...
```

And here is the class LocString :

```
@Entity
@Table(name="T_LOC_STRING")
public class LocString implements Serializable {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
@Column(name="ID")
private long id;

@Column(name="LOCALE")
private String locale;

@Column(name="VALUE")
private String value;
```

Right now, I have in my database an attribut with a Set of LocString which is already save.
I would like to create a new Attribut (with a new id) but using exactly the same Set of LocString (same reference in database, same reference in memory, same ids). When I try to save my attribut I have the following exception :

```
org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateSystemException: Found shared references
 to a collection: com.nomia.onmap.model.Attribut.label; nested exception is
 org.hibernate.HibernateException: Found shared references to a collection
```

How can I avoid this Exception. Is it something possible to do with hibernate ?

Thanks a lot in advance about your help

Clement